# Adding LED support in Samsung Artik 710 development module

Tags: linux, yocto

I want to control the two LED's (LED400 and LED401) on the Artik 710 development board through the Sys interface. To accomplish it, I modified the dtsi file of Artik710 in the Linux kernel. However, after building the image and booting the board, the LED's do not appear in the /sys/class directory. My code in the dtsi file is as follows

```
    gpio-leds {
            compatible = "gpio-leds";

            Blue {
                    label = "Blue";
                    gpios = <&gpio_a 28 0>;
                    linux,default-trigger = "heartbeat";
                    linux,default-state = "on";
            };

            Red {
                    label = "Red";
                    gpios = <&gpio_b 6 0>;
                    linux,default-trigger = "heartbeat";
                    linux,default-state = "on";
            };

    };
```

Can someone point the issue here?

Comment: Have you enabled the gpio-leds somewhere? (I.e. a line with `status = "okay";`?)

Comment: I am afraid not. I recently came to know that I need to enable the gpio-led driver in the configuration. However, there are so many configuration files present in the linux kernel and I am sort of confused which one to edit.

Comment: Well, sure you need to enable the driver in the kernel config. Then you need to have the dts-node `gpio-leds` enabled, by adding `status = "okay";` for instance below the `compatible = "gpio-leds";` line.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Anders. The led driver was not configured in the kernel. It is started to work fine as soon as I enabled it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there could be either of two cases:

1. You forgot to enable the kernel module
2. You forgot to enable the DT node, this is done by adding `status = "okay";`  in the node, eg below `compatible = "gpio-leds";`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't related to the dtsi file. I was facing the issue because the gpio-led driver was not configured in the kernel I was using ( the Linux kernel for Artik 710). As soon as I enabled it in the kernel configuration, the LED's started to work and appeared in the /sys/class directory.